# Cannot install SqlLocalDB 2016 on Windows 7 : FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15101

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-localdb

I downloaded SqlLocalDB.msi (Microsoft SQL Server 2016 LocalDB) using SQLServer2016-SSEI-Expr.exe (version 13.1804.4031.1).

I installed it and whatever I try to do I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn>SqlLocalDB.exe v
FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15101

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn>SqlLocalDB.exe i MSSQLLocalDB
FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15101
FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15105
```

The strange this is i could manage to create a new instance, in spite the error

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn>SqlLocalDB.exe create "test"
FormatMessageW failed. Error code returned: 15101
```

But I cannot connect to the original instance `MSSQLLocalDB` and any operation I try to execute from the command line gives me the same error.

I looked for the error number [here](http://sqlserverlearner.com/sql-server-error-list/sql-server-error-messages-list-14000-to-16000) but it seems like it has nothing to do with it.

In the instance I created I get the following:

```
select @@version
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 7 Enterprise 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Running on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

Comment: According to the MS docs, only Windows 8 and above are supported on [SQL Server 2016+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). Might not work at all, unfortunately.

Comment: You are right, I went over that page several times but just missed it. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Windows 10